# an assembly code to compare each element of the sets with one another

Tags: assembly, compare, x86-16, emu8086

compare two set of hexadecimal values which are located in two different memory segments (DS-0, ES-1) accordingly. Please, write an assembly code to compare each element of the sets with one another and then save bigger one in third memory segment(choose yourself). Sets are provided below.

First set:
0x3B
0x4C
0x73
0xE5
0x6D
0x8B
0x6C
0x17
0x6E
0x41
Second set:
0x3B
0x52
0x98
0x67
0x1F
0xAE
0x36
0xC9
0x70
0xED

Compare each set and save bigger in third memory segment

Comment: You can use `repz cmpsb` instruction, set `ds` and `es` to segments containing above strings of values, set `si` and `di` to beginnig of those strings, `cx = 10` because program checks 10 values, clear direction flag `cld` , we wanna check values going up in memory.

Comment: `es:[di]` is destination, `ds:[si]` is source. `cmpsb` compare bytes, `cmpsw` compares words and `cmpsd` compares double words.

Comment: @0Signal: `repz cmpsb` would only compare elements in matching positions, not each element of one set to every element of the other.  Maybe a `memcmp` is what the OP is looking for, though, and "set" is just an odd description of array or string.  If they were talking about each byte (hex value) separately, "save the bigger one" wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: This is a Q&A website, not a homework problem solving service.  If you want a good answer here, show your work and ask a specific question where you're having a problem, i.e. about the assembly language or how the processor works. If  you don't know where to start and are lost at the beginning, this website will not be able to teach you assembly programming in one question post.

Answer (score 0):

`repz cmpsb` works here but I don't know if this is right thing to do to use this instruction in this context, inside loop. Maybe `cmp` is better...? And too many `inc/dec si/di` instructions...

---- Update 1

Ok, now max values are copied to `data_set_3` in 3rd segment, but program shows ascii codes instead of values in hex/dec.

[image]

`stack SEGMENT stack     ;stack segment
    db 128 dup (?)
    stack_top   db ?    ;stack_top pointer to stack
stack ENDS

ds_data SEGMENT         ;ds segment

   data_set_1       db 3bh,4ch,73h,0e5h,6dh, 8bh,6ch,17h,6eh,41h
                       ;3bh,52h,98h, 67h,1fh,0aeh,36h,17h,70h,0edh
    position         db "Position ",'$'
    position_offset  db 0
     set_1            db "Data Set 1   ",'$'    
     set_2            db "Data Set 2   ",'$'    
     set_3            db "Data Set 3   ",'$'             
     
    elements_same    db " - Value 1 = Value 2",'$'
    elements_less    db " - Value 1 < Value 2",'$'
    elements_greater db " - Value 1 > Value 2",'$'
 
    result_msg db "Result - Data in 3rd segment",'$'
 
    newline db 13,10,'$'   

ds_data ENDS

es_data SEGMENT             ;es segment

    data_set_2 db 3bh,52h,98h,67h,1fh,0aeh,36h,17h,70h,0edh

es_data ENDS

result_data SEGMENT         ;result segment
    data_set_3   db 10 dup(?)
    set_3_offset dw 0
 
result_data ENDS

code SEGMENT

start:
    ;Set up segments
    mov ax, seg stack
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, offset stack_top
  
    mov ax, seg ds_data
    mov ds, ax
  
    mov ax, seg es_data
    mov es, ax  
  
    mov si, offset ds:data_set_1    ;offset to source string
    mov di, offset es:data_set_2    ;offset to destination string

   cld    ; clear direction flag, increase adresses
  
   mov cx,10    

   mov ah,9    ;new line
   mov dx,offset newline
   int 21h        

   check_elements:              ; compare 10 elements one by one
       push cx
      
       mov cx,1         
       repz cmpsb               ; compare ds:[si] to es:[di]
                            ; set flags
                            ; values same ZF = 1
                            ; src value is less than destination value CF = 1
                            ; src value is greater than destination value CF = 0, ZF = 0

       pushf                    ;push flags on stack
    
       call text_position
    
       popf             ;pop flags
;----------------------------------------------     
       ja src_greater_than_dest     ;src > dest
       jb src_less_than_dest            ;src < dest        
       ;else src = dest

       call text_src_equals_dest
       dec si
       dec di
    
       push es  
       mov ax, seg result_data
       mov es, ax   

       mov bx, offset es:data_set_3         ;offset to result string    
       add bx,es:[set_3_offset]             ;position in result string
       mov al,  [si]                            ;copy value to result string
       mov es:[bx],al
       inc es:[set_3_offset]                    ;next position in result string
       pop es           
        
       inc si
       inc di
    
       jmp check_element_done
  
       src_greater_than_dest:           
        
           call text_src_greater_dest

           dec si
           dec di       
        
           push es  
           mov ax, seg result_data
           mov es, ax   

           mov bx, offset es:data_set_3         ;offset to result string    
           add bx,es:[set_3_offset]             ;position in result string
           mov al,  [si]                            ;copy value to result string
           mov es:[bx],al
           inc es:[set_3_offset]                    ;next position in result string
           pop es           
        
           inc si
           inc di           
    
           jmp check_element_done

       src_less_than_dest:          
        
           call text_src_less_dest
        
           dec si
           dec di   
           mov al,  es:[di]                             ;copy value to result string
                    
           push es  
           push ax
           mov ax, seg result_data
           mov es, ax   

           mov bx, offset es:data_set_3         ;offset to result string    
           add bx,es:[set_3_offset]             ;position in result string
           pop ax
           mov es:[bx],al
           inc es:[set_3_offset]                    ;next position in result string
           pop es           
        
           inc si
           inc di           
        
       check_element_done:
           pop cx
           inc ds:[position_offset]

   loop check_elements

;Print data_set_1
mov ah,9                    ; new line
mov dx,offset newline
int 21h     
        
mov ah,9                    ; print "Data Set 1   "
mov dx,offset set_1 
int 21h     

mov cx,10   
mov bx, offset data_set_1
    
Show_data_set_1:
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,[bx] 
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,' '
    int 21h
    inc bx
loop Show_data_set_1    

;Print data_set_2
mov ah,9                    ; new line
mov dx,offset newline
int 21h     
        
mov ah,9                    ; print "Data Set 2   "
mov dx,offset set_2 
int 21h     

mov cx,10               
mov bx, offset es:data_set_2
    
Show_data_set_2:
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,es:[bx]  
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,' '
    int 21h
    inc bx
loop Show_data_set_2

;Print data_set_3
mov ah,9                    ; new line
mov dx,offset newline
int 21h     
        
mov ah,9                    ; print "Data Set 3   "
mov dx,offset set_3
int 21h                 

mov cx,10
mov ax, seg result_data ;change segment to result_data
mov es, ax              
mov bx, offset es:data_set_3
    
Show_data_set_3:
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,es:[bx]  
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,' '
    int 21h
    inc bx
loop Show_data_set_3

mov ah,9                    ; new line
mov dx,offset newline
int 21h     

end_program:     
    ; Terminate program
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
;--------------------------
text_position proc
    mov ah,9                        ; print "Position"
    mov dx,offset position
    int 21h
        
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,ds:[position_offset]     ; print position number
    add dl,30h
    int 21h
    ret
text_position endp

text_src_equals_dest proc
    mov ah,9                        ; print "Src = Destination"
    mov dx,offset elements_same
    int 21h     
        
    mov ah,9                        ; new line
    mov dx,offset newline
    int 21h      
    ret
text_src_equals_dest endp

text_src_greater_dest proc
    mov ah,9                    ; print "Src > Destination"
    mov dx,offset elements_greater
    int 21h     
        
    mov ah,9                    ; new line
    mov dx,offset newline
    int 21h      
    ret
text_src_greater_dest endp

text_src_less_dest proc
        mov ah,9                    ; print "Src < Destination"
        mov dx,offset elements_less
        int 21h     
        
        mov ah,9                    ; new line
        mov dx,offset newline
        int 21h      
    ret
text_src_less_dest endp

code ENDS
END start`